# Is there a search algorithm/method that matches phrases?

Tags: algorithm, search

I am trying to make a search tool that would search a small number of objects (about 1000, each with about 3 text fields I want to search) for a given phrase.

I was trying to find an algorithm that would rank the search results for me.  Lots of topics lead to Fuzzy matching, and the Levenshtein distance algorithm, but that doesn’t seem appropriate for this case (for example, it would say the phrase “cats and dogs” is closer to “cars and cogs” than it is to “dogs and cats”).

Is there an algorithm/method dedicated to matching a search phrase against other blocks of text, and ranking the results according to things like the text being equal, the search phrase being contained, individual words being contained etc.  I don’t even know what is normally appropriate.

I usually code in c#.  I am not using a data base.

Comment: You need Google-style statistical correlations.  Do you have a lot of data to train with?  1000 objects is not much training data.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/features.html). It can perform all sort of text indexing, return ranked results, and lots of other good stuff. There's an implementation in C#. It might be a bit overkill for your use case, but it's such an excellent and useful technology that you should really have a look into it, it's almost certain you will find good use for it during your career.